# How to get desired result with full-text search in SQL Server through thesaurus?

Tags: sql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing, sql-server-2019, thesaurus

I am using SQL Server 2019. I define thesaurus in language XML in SQL Server full text search.

```
<XML ID="Microsoft Search Thesaurus">
<thesaurus xmlns="x-schema:tsSchema.xml">
<diacritics_sensitive>0</diacritics_sensitive>
    <expansion>
        <sub>DNA typing</sub>
        <sub>genetic fingerprinting</sub>
    </expansion>
</thesaurus>
</XML>
```

As thesaurus and prefix form (*) can not be used inside **contains** statement such as

```
SELECT * 
FROM new_framework_text ft 
WHERE CONTAINS (ft.text, N'FORMSOF (THESAURUS,"DNA typing*")')
```

Usually, I use this query for get result, but it is not actually return desired result.

```
SELECT * 
FROM new_framework_text ft 
WHERE CONTAINS (ft.text, N'FORMSOF (THESAURUS, "DNA typing") OR "DNA typing*"')
```

Above, query will return rows with 'DNA typing', 'genetic fingerprinting' and 'DNA typing*'.

It can not get the rows start with thesaurus word which is 'genetic fingerprinting*'.

I do not want to write static code in project, because there will be a lot of thesaurus in future.

I searched the internet, but can not find any valid answer.

How can I achieve to get needed records with just only query?

Comment: Full-Text is primarily designed as a similar-word search, it's not really designed for wildcard searches

Comment: @Charlieface So it means there is no way to do it except write static code?

Comment: You could build a thesaurus yourself perhaps? `Thesaurus` table with each word referencing synonyms, then you can do a search `LIKE synonym + '%'`

Comment: @Charlieface Actually, there are a lot of data. For this case, LIKE is not recommended.

Comment: I wouldn't say that: `LIKE` with a prefix and a wildcard only at the end is fine. The problems start when the wildcard is at the beginning

Comment: @Charlieface I did not know it, can you reference to this, please?

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning also https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/06/sargable-why-string-is-slow/